# Nginx balancer manager gui

Tags: user-interface, nginx, load-balancing

is there any Gui or CLI for NGINX load balancer? Something like the balancer manager web gui of Apache.
I need quick commands for marking an instance UP or DOWN, possibly without editing and reloading the whole configuration file.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is. Unfortunately, it's only available for NGINX Plus. If you're curious, you can check it out in action on their demo site.

http://demo.nginx.com/status.html

If anybody knows of an alternative, feel free to comment.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can try:

[ng-admin.jslsolucoes.com](https://github.com/jslsolucoes/nginx-admin)

Another one:

[Ajenti](http://ajenti.org/)